# ERROR: invalid character ' ' in literal true (expecting 'e') - POST API JSON

Tags: javascript, json, post, pentaho

I am trying to use the POST method to insert some data from a person with JSON. I am using the code from JS to construct, but when i start the transformation, it sends me:

> "ERROR: invalid character ' ' in literal true (expecting 'e')".

Does anyone know how to solve it?

```js
const obj = {
  "num_matricula": num_matricula,
  "limit_date": "2022-05-20",
  "admission_date": admission_date,
  "cost_center": cost_center,
  "pos_number": pos_number,
  "role": role,
  "department": department,
  "pagamento": {
    "vinculo": vinculo,
    "valor": valor,
    "recorrencia": recorrencia,
    "contaBancaria": {
      "banco": "001",
      "carta": "c9160763-db6c-4e8c-a1ad-ad8709c99be2"
    }
  },
  "deficiencia": deficiencia,
  "jornada": jornada,
  "profile": {
    "name": name,
    "email": email,
    "mobile": mobile
  },
  "exame": {
    "clinica": "6dc84ce4-7d9f-48ec-b9b1-a8a895a21fd4",
    "data": "2022-05-15",
    "hora": "14:00",
    "obs": "Comparecer de manhã",
    "guia": "e37dab24-c7a4-4b92-b9d1-32ed538b8300",
  },
  "docs": ["c9e26093-5e0c-4bd2-bea3-ac5182a6179f"],
  "send_sms": true,
  "send_email": true
};
const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Some columns are already provided with data from previous step (you can see in the images below), that is why i just repeated the column name in the JS code. Just to let you know, the boolean types of data are the columns: send_email, send_sms and deficiencia.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The code you posted is not getting an error. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: What makes me confused it is because i wrote 'true' right but it tells about the 'e'.

Comment: Sounds like something is modifying or truncating the JSON before you try to parse it. Show the code that parses it.

Comment: After the step to create the JS code in pentaho, the only thing i did was to send the information to the API POST method. Im gonna try to send an image about it.

Comment: Post code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: The only code i am using is this one from JS, the rest i am using steps from Pentaho.

Comment: If Penatoho is generating the actual code from a GUI code builder, this sounds like a bug in Penataho.

Comment: Did you try with `"send_sms": 1` and/or `"send_email": 1`? Sometimes APIs have difficulty with the words `true` and `false`, i.e. if they're converted to strings `'true'` and `'false'`, instead of `0`/`1`, etc. I haven't seen that specific error message before though, so that's a shot in the dark 

Comment: When i change the values to numbers like you supposed, it sends me : "unexpected end of json input".

Comment: I think it is something with the boolean values because when i change it for string values like "true", it sends me the second error that i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JSON is a string.  So in your first line you see this is not valid json:  "num_matricula": num_matricula,

only numbers can be without double quotes:  "num_matricula": 1234,

Comment: Thats the error when you run the code snippet

Comment: That is true, but i did this because im not mentioning a string withou doubles quotes, but the column from previous step. The next step, the num_matricula without double quotes is replaced by the string value assigned as you can see in one of the screenshots.